# Why am I still able to get a response on port 80 when I've shut down all ports except 22?

Tags: ssh, iptables, port

My goal is to shut down absolutely all ports on my Ubuntu server, except port 22 (SSH).

I followed the instructions from [this question here on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/363741/how-can-i-block-all-but-three-ports-in-ubuntu), plus instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37413/how-do-i-shut-down-ports-remotely-without-shutting-myself-out).

However, after going through the instructions, it seems like my ports are still open. Here's port 80, for example:

```
$ nmap -p 80 ###.###.###.###

Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2012-05-09 15:36 JST
Nmap scan report for ###-###-###-###.name.name.com (###.###.###.###)
Host is up (0.0065s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.63 seconds
```

Here is the contents of my iptables:

```
# sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh 
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Just looking at it, especialy where it says "Accept all anywhere", it seems like I have the opposite of what I want. It looks like instead of closing down ports, I've opened them up. However, these are the results of following the instructions to the letter, so maybe I just don't understand what the terms really mean.

In any case, bottom line, what do I do to shut down all ports except 22, and then make it stick even if the server gets rebooted. Surely it's just a few commands at the command line?

*(Please note I'm a web designer who got this task, so I'm not at all a super confident server admin. Please make answers easy to understand. Thanks!)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you expected the line:

```
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

means all protocols/ports are allowed since it comes before this line:

```
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

You are not denying any port since there is only one `DROP` rule that comes after an `ACCEPT` rule which is allowing everything.

`iptables` rules are **matched in order**, so you need to have the following rules if you want to allow only port 22 to be allowed on INPUT chain:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

The above two rules should be enough with default `INPUT` policy set to `DROP` as indicated in the line:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
```

To make your rule-set persistent, you can use `iptables-save > rules_file` to dump your rule-set to a text file. Then, it can be loaded during server startup by including it in any script using `iptables-restore`.